# How to pass Philippine Currency in QRegExp?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qregexp

I am currently studying Regex and I came up in this regex:

```
r"\₱[0-9]*[.]{,1}[0-9]{,2}"
```

for QRegExp is and currently It is only good if it starts with `₱` other than that my app is breaking is there a way to get these following formats:

```
100.0
100.00
₱100.00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
r"₱?\d+(?:\.[0-9]{,2})?"
```

The escape before the `₱` symbol is not needed. I also made the rest a bit more concise and faster, so the engine doesn't need to uselessly backtrack, by making the whole decimal section optional, but the decimal point mandatory within that group, and I replaced `[0-9]` with the more semantic `\d`. Presumably you will want at least one digit, so I took the liberty to change `*` to `+`.

Comment: thank you for answering! I'm confused between these format r"₱?\d+(?:\.[0-9]{,2})?" and the format that is something like this: /^(\$?([0-9]*\.?\d{2}?)$)/ is there a way so that I can distinguish it ?

Comment: As Eagnir said, regex101 is a good site that can explain regular expressions. Besides, there is https://www.regular-expressions.info/ as well as Stack Overflow's canonical [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean).

Answer (score 0):

You should make `₱` optional by changing `\₱` to `[\₱]{0,1}`

```
r"[\₱]{0,1}[0-9]*[.]{0,1}[0-9]{0,2}"
```

*Note: I always use `{0,1}` syntax and not `{,1}` to ensure the next developer is clear on what it does.*

### Conditions

1. May or may not start with the character `₱`
2. Number must have a decimal point
3. It cannot detect negative numbers
4. It will not accept more than 2 position after the decimal point

### External Regex Fiddle

https://regex101.com/r/dBk1Dq/1

Comment: Thank you sir is there a manual or text book where I can read about regExp that you can recommend to me?

Comment: You should use https://regex101.com, it has references, examples as well as explanation on different syntax. The best is you can try the regex right away and figure it out while changing it.